# GWT. Where to register event handlers(eventBus) within MVP pattern

Tags: java, gwt, mvp

Where best place to register event handlers when using MVP paradigm? I know that application wide events must be registered  in "AppController", but I need to rise event from one presenter, and second presenter must handle it . So is better to define eventHandler inside AppController, or better to define eventHander inside second presenter (rise this event in 1st presenter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application wide events don't necessarily have to be registered in the `AppControler`.
I don't think it actually actually where you register them as long as you pass around and use one global singleton `EventBus`.
Normally you pass this global `EventBus`  to your various Presenters via a constructor parameter (using dependency injection for example).

In the first presenter you can register for a specific event which is fired by the second presenter on the global `EventBus`.